# What is vanilla Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

What does the term vanilla maven means in below statement?

While we use vanilla Maven to compile, test, and package Java code, a key Maven plug-in we use is Spotify’s Docker plugin. This plugin allows us to kick off the creation of a Docker build right from within Maven.

Comment: I think in this context vanilla maven means only maven without any third party plugin.

Comment: Is it without third party plugin or any other plugins?

Comment: It's third-party plugin. By default maven uses lots of plugin developed by Maven team them self

Comment: See the list of plugins developed within Apache Software Foundation (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/)...